# How do I jump over this gap?

Tags: super-mario-world

I am trying to reach the next level in the SM world [here](https://supermario64.net/unblocked-games/super-mario-world) but I got stuck in the 1st world level. Actually, I am not able to jump Mario over as seen in the screenshot below. My Mario size is also big as he ate the mushroom. But still when I press A the jump is not too high that's why Mario is not able to jump over there. Anyone who plays this game on browser not on NS? If yes please let me know how to reach the next world by successfully jumping there.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running/jumping, you need to keep pressing your Run key to run faster/jump higher. I just tested it, it's enough to pass this section.

Comment: Is there any key on the keyboard to run faster? Actually, I also jumped while running from right to left

Comment: You can parameter the keys in the main menu and one of them is the run option, I would advise doing it.

Comment: It seems the default key is S. So, hold S and press A to do a high jump.

Comment: yeah it works, great,  thank you.